# STS Boot dashboard doesn't show the starting port port

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I've just started to use Boot Dashboard to manage all my Spring Boot application ([Boot Dashboard](https://spring.io/blog/2015/10/08/the-spring-boot-dashboard-in-sts-part-1-local-boot-apps)).

The problem is that I can't see the starting port of my applications:

[image: My Boot Dashboard]

The applications start without any problem:

```
Started Application in 4.337 seconds (JVM running for 4.953)
```

I'm using STS 3.7.1, Spring Boot 1.2.6.RELEASE and java 1.8.

Why Boot Dashboard doesn't show me the starting port of my applications?

Answer (score 2):

This particular feature is supported with Spring Boot 1.3.0 .

http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html

> Note: some features of the dashboard like port discovery need a very
>   recent version of boot (1.3)

Comment: Ok, let me test this with spring boot 1.3

Answer (score 1):

I added the following dependency in my POM and it worked:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this is not the solution, I can still see issues hanging in around related to port number.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved for me by commenting WebApplicationType.NONE

```
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.demo")
    public class Application {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
        
        public static void main(final String... args) {
            final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
            //app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
            app.run(args);
        }
}
```