# STS Spring Boot Dashboard Doesn't Recognize Successful Start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129818/sts-boot-dashboard-doesnt-show-the-starting-port-port), but the Spring "Boot Dashboard" doesn't show as starting (the 'up arrow' icon); specifically the first two applications in the list below.

[image: spring boot dashboard]

I could care less about the icon, but the resulting impact is that the applications cannot shutdown via the Boot Dashboard (required `kill -9`).

The applications start without any problem:

```
Started Application in 1.337 seconds (JVM running for 1.998)
```

All three applications are using the latest `spring-boot-starter-parent` version, [`1.3.1.RELEASE`](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3Aspring%2Dboot%2Dstarter%2Dparent).

The third application's start is reflected correctly, but I'm not sure where to look--within STS or within my app config--to troubleshoot the issue.

My STS version is:

```
Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201511261048
Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)
```

Comment: A co-worker suggested adding the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency, but this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: The port is being retrieved from the boot app by communicating with some JMX beans inside. Can you take a look at the launch config to see if some JMX port is being defined and activated? If so, maybe that port is occupied by some other running app (maybe you use the same port for all three apps).

Comment: If the port was occupied the app would crash trying to bind to it. But yes, most likely the failure to detect that app has started is somehow conected with a failure to connect to that JMX bean. This probably has something to do with the fact that your apps are setup in a slightly 'unusual' way. Any chance you could provide a 'sample' app to reproduce this? Without that it will be rather hard to figure out specifically what is going on here.

Comment: @MartinLippert/@Kris -- there are not port collisions.  The applications start without any problem, and are accessible RESTfully as-expected.  Spring Boot dashboard does not reflect their "started" status correctly.  The issue further manifests at shutdown: they do not *stop* gracefully.

Comment: I would suggest to file an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and attach a sample project. This would help a lot to track this down. Maybe also include the launch config of your project into the project, that might be interesting, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide a sample app and I will debug the issue and then we can fix and/or provide a more precise answer to your question.

Without a sample app the best I can do is give vague hints that 'something' seems to be going wrong with the JMX lifecycle mgmt bean.

There may be a workaround you can use. The 'life-cycle-bean' support can be turned off explicitly and then you will fallback on pre boot 1.3 behavior for the dash. (This means STS will not distinguish 'starting' from 'running' state and will not use a 'ask nicely' approach to terminate the process but just forcefully shut it down).

If that's good enough for you then open the launch config for your app (e.g. by selecting it and clicking the 'pencil' button in the dash) and deselect the appropriate checkbox. See screenshot below:

[image]